# How to do array walk with the dynamic variable?

Tags: php, arrays

```
 array (size=2)
 0 => 
 array (size=7)
  'id' => string '66' (length=2)
  'room_name' => string 'Luxury' (length=6)
  'no_of_room' => string '0' (length=1)
  'price' => string '1000' (length=4)
  'description' => string 'dfh dvsrtruub  dsgd' (length=19)
  'image' => string 'arrow.jpg' (length=9)
  'hotel_id' => string '1' (length=1)
 1 => 
 array (size=7)
  'id' => string '65' (length=2)
  'room_name' => string 'Deluxe' (length=6)
  'no_of_room' => string '4' (length=1)
  'price' => string '800' (length=3)
  'description' => string 'rybsvssfd' (length=9)
  'image' => string '2P2Z4.png' (length=9)
  'hotel_id' => string '1' (length=1)
```

hi this is array when i do var_dump. I want to walk array and add two element inside each array. I want is:

```
 $checkin = "2014-2-4"  //i will be changed according to textbox value.

 array (size=2)
 0 => 
 array (size=8)
  'id' => string '66' (length=2)
  'room_name' => string 'Luxury' (length=6)
  'no_of_room' => string '0' (length=1)
  'price' => string '1000' (length=4)
  'description' => string 'dfh dvsrtruub  dsgd' (length=19)
  'image' => string 'arrow.jpg' (length=9)
  'hotel_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  'check_in_date' => null
  1 => 
  array (size=8)
  'id' => string '65' (length=2)
  'room_name' => string 'Deluxe' (length=6)
  'no_of_room' => string '2' (length=1)
  'price' => string '800' (length=3)
  'description' => string 'rybsvssfd' (length=9)
  'image' => string '2P2Z4.png' (length=9)
  'hotel_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  'check_in_date' => null

 array_walk($jsonArray, create_function('&$subarray', '$subarray[check_in_date] =$check_in;'));
```

In above array_walk function when i use $check_in, it gives me null but not the value. Why is there something wrong or array_walk i not used for my purpose. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you know the key to the array? Is that a 2d array or single array?

Comment: its think its 2d array.. But not sure. I need to pass the key assigning certain string name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For PHP 5.3+**

If you're using PHP 5.3+, you can use an anonymous function with `use` syntax to import the variable into the function scope:

```
array_walk($jsonArray, function (&$subarray) use ($checkin) {
    $subarray['check_in_date'] = $checkin;
});
```

**For older versions of PHP**

If you're using an older version of PHP, you might be stuck using `create_function()`. You can use the `global` keyword to import the variable into the function scope. Note that it's hacky and you really should consider upgrading your PHP version instead of using this approach:

```
array_walk($array, create_function(
    '&$subarray', 
    'global $checkin; $subarray["check_in_date"] = $checkin;'
));
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/149520)